# Mysql: How many times a value appear in each line

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have a table I'm using to develop a card game and it's columns represent the powers for each card. Like strength, speed, magic, etc. I'll just use letters in the example:

```
 a  | b  | c  | d  | e  | f
----+----+----+----+----+----
 12 | 0  | 0  | 12 | 0  | 12
 8  | 8  | 6  | 5  | 6  | 3
 3  | 7  | 1  | 11 | 7  | 7
 0  | 12 | 12 | 12 | 0  | 0
 10 | 2  | 12 | 10 | 0  | 2
```

As you can see, the numbers range from 0 to 12 and every card must sum up 36 points. That gives me 204763 possible combinations. I already generated them. Right now, I'm creating filters to select the cards that will make it to the final game.

What I'm trying to achieve is to select all cards that have 12 in three columns (those would be the best cards in the game). How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugly, but

```
SELECT (a = 12) + (b = 12) + (c = 12) + .... + (f = 12) AS twelves
...
HAVING twelves >= 3
```